# Cannot call method Java

Tags: java

I tried to write a generic SelectionSort, but there are error suggesting in my `sort()`, I cannot call `findMinIndex(int,int)` or `swap()` though I can call in `main()`. How can I modify my code to rectify this problem?

```
public class SelectionSort<T extends Comparable<T>>{
 T[] result = null;
static int size = 0;
SelectionSort(T[] a){
    result = a;
    size = a.length;
}
public int findMinIndex(int begin, int end){
    T min = result[begin];
    int index = begin;
    while(begin<=end){
        if(result[begin].compareTo(min)<0){
            min = result[begin];
            index = begin;
        }
        begin++;
    }
    return index;
}
public void swap(int i, int j){
    T temp = result[i];
    result[i]=result[j];
    result[j]=temp;
}
private int getSize(){
    return size;
}

public  void sort(){
    int have_sorted_till = -1;
    int index = -1;
    while(have_sorted_till<size){
        index = result.findMinIndex(have_sorted_till+1,size-1);
        result.swap(index, have_sorted_till+1);
        have_sorted_till++;
    }
}

public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        s = s + result[i]+",";
    }
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Double[] a =  new Double[]{2.2,5.7,2.8,9.7,3.9,12.3};
    SelectionSort<Double> b = new SelectionSort<Double>(a);
    b.swap(0,5);
        System.out.print(b.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: "result.findMinIndex", should it just be "findMinIndex" without "result."? Same with "swap". "result" is an array, not a "SelectionSort".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to call a class method on an array. This does not work.

```
    index = result.findMinIndex(have_sorted_till+1,size-1);
    result.swap(index, have_sorted_till+1);
```

`result` is your generic array. Just call the method directly

```
    index = findMinIndex(have_sorted_till+1,size-1);
    swap(index, have_sorted_till+1);
```